Rust Local time always returns UTC on target
The following code works fine on my host system
use chrono::{Local};

fn main()
{
let local_dt = Local::now();
println!("local_dt {}", local_dt);
}


local_dt 2024-06-10 16:13:46.339768796 -04:00

But when I run it on my target (armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) it always returns the UTC time.
The target's /etc/TZ is configured ("EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0") and returns the correct datetime.
$date
Mon Jun 10 16:14:27 EDT 2024
If I write C code and extern it and call it from my Rust application then it works fine as well. It is just the native Rust code that only seems understand UTC time.
int print_time ()
{
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm *info;
   time( &rawtime );
   info = localtime( &rawtime );
   printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(info));
   return(0);
}

extern "C" { fn print_time(); }
...
let local_dt = Local::now();
println!("local_dt {}", local_dt);
unsafe{ print_time(); }`


local_dt 2024-06-10 20:30:15.344901619 +00:00 
Current local time and date: Mon Jun 10 16:30:15 2024

I have also tried settings the TZ directly and that DOES change the C output, but Rust is still just UTC.
    let local_dt = Local::now();
    println!("local_dt {}", local_dt);
    unsafe{ print_time(); }

    let key = "TZ";
    println!("TZ {:?}", env::var(key));
    env::set_var(key, "PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0");
    println!("TZ {:?}", env::var(key));

    let local_dt = Local::now();
    println!("local_dt {}", local_dt);
    unsafe{ print_time(); }


local_dt 2024-06-10 20:38:46.517170940 +00:00 
Current local time and date: Mon Jun 10 16:38:46 2024 
TZ Err(NotPresent) 
TZ Ok("PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0") 
local_dt 2024-06-10 20:38:46.517983048 +00:00 
Current local time and date: Mon Jun 10 13:38:46 2024

EDIT
One big Caveat. I guess I didn't give the set_var "time to work". If I repeat the code again later (with the application still running) then now Local time is now correct.

local_dt 2024-06-10 13:47:29.738219435 -07:00 
Current local time and date: Mon Jun 10 13:47:29 2024 
TZ Ok("PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0") 
TZ Ok("PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0") 
local_dt 2024-06-10 13:47:29.739639177 -07:00 
Current local time and date: Mon Jun 10 13:47:29 2024

So that may answer my question, but in the meantime is there a better (more Rust-like) solution I should be looking for.

Can you try to set the TZ environment variable instead? According to the source, it checks this variable and assumes UTC if it isn't defined. (Edit: I meant setting it outside the program since chrono caches the result. With your edit this may explain what is happening)

I agree with @FilipeRodrigues, also there can be multiple scopes of configuration, IE: the hosts base config and user config if your application is running in a user-session.

Can't contribute Rust expertise but time zone libs normally check other time zone indicators besides the TZ env var; on Unix derivatives you could try /etc/localtime or the SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/TimeZoneInformation reg key on Windows. "get local tz" is kind of a guessing game but I'd suspect chrono to do this as well, no? Or would you need chrono-tz for this?

Looks like setting the TZ variable from std::env::set_var solved my problem. Setting TZ before launching the process didn't help, but that is fine.
